# Add whitespace formatting to TSQL FOR XML data

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I'm exporting data from joined SQL tables as XML then inserting it into a script that will be used to import it.

I would like the XML to be split across lines and indented in the output script. How do I add whitespace formatting to the XML generated with FOR XML

Here's an example that uses AdventureWorks2014 sample database:

```
DECLARE @XmlData xml = (
    SELECT e.BusinessEntityID, e.HireDate, e.JobTitle, c.FirstName, c.MiddleName, c.LastName
    FROM HumanResources.Employee e 
        INNER JOIN Person.Person c
       ON c.BusinessEntityID = e.BusinessEntityID
    WHERE c.FirstName = 'Rob'
    FOR XML AUTO, ROOT);

DECLARE @ScriptTemplate nvarchar(max) = '
-- This is my import script
-- blah, blah, blah

DECLARE @SolutionXml as xml = ''
##REPLACE_THIS##
'';

DECLARE @SolutionXmlHandle int;
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @SolutionXmlHandle OUTPUT, @SolutionXml;

-- blah, blah, blah
';

DECLARE @myScript nvarchar(max) = REPLACE (@ScriptTemplate, '##REPLACE_THIS##', CONVERT(nvarchar(max), @XmlData, 1))

SELECT @XmlData XmlData, @ScriptTemplate ScriptTemplate, @myScript myScript
```

Comment: This will be very annoyingly complicated and involved in T-SQL - would be much easier to get that XML out to a middle tier and do the "massaging" of the XML there in a full-fledged programming language like C#, Ruby, Java or whatever else you might be using ....

Answer (score 0):

If you really must do this in the stored procedure, your best bet is to add a CLR library to SQL Server with a function like the following

```
public static string FormatXML(string xmlData)
{
  XDocument xd = XDocument.Parse(xmlData);
  return xd.ToString();
}
```

see http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/10/19/sql-server-introduction-to-clr-simple-example-of-clr-stored-procedure/ for more information about SQL CLR.